# Smarty: two templates in one controller

Tags: smarty

How can I use two different templates from controller in Smarty?
I made an "if" for this aim `(if (condition1){use template1}else{use template2})`, but I don't have an idea what to check for to condition return "true".

In my template where i use this combination:

```
{init_module module="catalog" action="sizesAction"}
```

(in sizesAction method there are assigning view to template1.tpl)
So how can I define where it will be using template1.tpl and where template2.tpl.
I tryed to describe the issue as detailed as possible. How it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that

```
{init_module module="catalog" action="sizesAction"}
```

is your custom Smarty plugin.

So in index.tpl you simple place

```
{init_module module="catalog" action="sizesAction"}
```

And in init_module function you can do something like that:

```
  $ntemplate = $template->createTemplate('your_template.tpl');

  $ntemplate->assign ('var' , 'foo');

  return $ntemplate->fetch();
```

You can simple extend it to use it for example that way:

```
  $x = 5; 

  if ($x > 2) {
      $tpl = 'template1.tpl';
  } 
  else  {
      $tpl = 'template2.tpl';
 }


  $ntemplate = $template->createTemplate($tpl);

  $ntemplate->assign ('var' , 'foo');

  return $ntemplate->fetch();
```

If it is not what you ask, you need to make your question clear and give samples of your code.